# writing an array to a raster file with spatial attributes using array2raster. ` AttributeError: NoneType`

Tags: python, arrays, geospatial, raster

I have two scripts. One uses hydrology tools and finds the depths of sinks in a dem and outputs a binary sink/no-sink array. The other script labels pixel groups. After this I have a function `array2raster` from [here](https://gist.github.com/jkatagi/a1207eee32463efd06fb57676dcf86c8?permalink_comment_id=3248112) To generate a spatial image from the array. The function takes an array, which I am attempting to convert to a raster which in this case is a label image, and it takes a raster with spatial attributes as inputs.

The funtion `array2raster` works when I keep the scripts separate and just transfer the data from script 1 to the segmentation script. However, when I incorporate the two scripts into one, and that resultant script calls `array2raster`, I get the error: `AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute  "SetGeotransform"`.

I checked the inputs, `dataset` and  `array` in the case of both the incorporated script and the separate script. In both cases they are a `gdal.Dataset` and a `numpy.array`. Also, I am using the same input raster in each case, so I am not too sure what the difference is between the scripts that is causing an error only in one.

EDIT

[full script](https://github.com/maxduso/CD_identification/blob/daab633a71671b947840a3f1d5e1615c52a93f72/whitebox_X_scikit.py)

---

Output of the first part of the script

```
sink_depth = wbt.depth_in_sink(
                        input_path,
                        output_path,
                        zero_background= True
)
```

Read in the output of part one to continue analysis

```
spatial_image = gdal.Open(output_path)
```

---

Conversion of input array to raster using spatial information from `spatial_image`

```
def array2raster(newRasterfn, dataset, array, dtype):
    """
    save GTiff file from numpy.array
    input:
        newRasterfn: save file name
        dataset : original tif file with spatial information
        array : numpy.array 
        dtype: Byte or Float32.
    """
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]
    originX, pixelWidth, b, originY, d, pixelHeight = dataset.GetGeoTransform() 

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

    # set data type to save.
    GDT_dtype = gdal.GDT_Unknown
    if dtype == "Byte": 
        GDT_dtype = gdal.GDT_Byte
    elif dtype == "Float32":
        GDT_dtype = gdal.GDT_Float32
    else:
        print("Not supported data type.")

    # set number of band.
    if array.ndim == 2:
        band_num = 1
    else:
        band_num = array.shape[2]

    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, band_num, GDT_dtype)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))

    # Loop over all bands.
    for b in range(band_num):
        outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(b + 1)
        # Read in the band's data into the third dimension of our array
        if band_num == 1:
            outband.WriteArray(array)
        else:
            outband.WriteArray(array[:,:,b])

    # setteing srs from input tif file.
    prj=dataset.GetProjection()
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()
    print(prj)


array2raster("tif_folder/out_raster.tif", spatial_image, filtered_labels, "Byte")
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'`

It seems as though the issue is in the creation of `outRaster` which is a class: NoneType. This is in turn created by the line `driver.Create()`, all the inputs to driver.Create are the correct format as far as I can tell, so I am wondering if it is an issue with the driver itself, which is defined above with `driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')`. Agan though, this method worked in a different script.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtunately, I do not see your script as a whole.

Please check, whether you did smth like `spatial_image = gdal.Open(path)` before running this function.

Comment: MM I figured that the script was too long to share in a post. I suppose I could add it to a git hub repository which I could link to although that will take me a little bit to figure out. Yes, I read in the spatial  image like this: `spatial_image = gdal.Open(output_path)` where `output_path` is the path that was used in the previous code chunk to write the result to the computer. I will add this edit to the question above.